# Can I replace one of the subplots (in a 2-by-2 matrix) with a table?

Tags: tables, graphics, subfloats

```latex
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[]{subfig}

\begin{figure}[hbt!]
    \centering
    \subfloat[\label{Airline:a}]{\includegraphics[width=0.46\textwidth]{a.eps}} \quad
    \subfloat[\label{Airline:b}]{\includegraphics[width=0.46\textwidth]{b.eps}} \\
    \subfloat[\label{Airline:c}]{\includegraphics[width=0.46\textwidth]{c.eps}} \quad
    \subfloat[\label{Airline:d}]{\includegraphics[width=0.46\textwidth]{d.eps}} \\
    \caption{Descriptive Statistics}
    \label{Airline}
\end{figure}
```

Previously, I arranged four plots in a 2-by-2 matrix. Can I substitute the fourth plot with a table? If yes, how? Also I think I need to **tweak the size** of the table to fit in the subplots matrix?

```latex
\begin{tabular}{lrrrrrrrrrr}
\toprule
{} &     0 &     1 &     2 &     3 &     4 &     5 &     6 &     7 &     8 &     9 \\
\midrule
0  &  0.00 & 14.45 &  9.33 &  9.14 & 10.77 &  7.52 &  8.15 & 11.86 &  9.91 & 11.49 \\
1  & 14.45 &  0.00 & 10.13 & 11.73 & 10.17 & 11.12 & 10.61 & 10.74 & 10.09 &  9.93 \\
2  &  9.33 & 10.13 &  0.00 &  8.18 &  7.93 &  7.91 &  7.33 &  8.87 &  7.08 &  8.89 \\
3  &  9.14 & 11.73 &  8.18 &  0.00 &  9.09 &  6.12 &  9.30 &  8.92 &  7.02 &  8.35 \\
4  & 10.77 & 10.17 &  7.93 &  9.09 &  0.00 &  8.00 &  8.78 &  7.58 &  7.38 &  6.01 \\
5  &  7.52 & 11.12 &  7.91 &  6.12 &  8.00 &  0.00 &  6.70 &  9.21 &  6.97 &  8.26 \\
6  &  8.15 & 10.61 &  7.33 &  9.30 &  8.78 &  6.70 &  0.00 & 10.89 &  8.59 & 10.44 \\
7  & 11.86 & 10.74 &  8.87 &  8.92 &  7.58 &  9.21 & 10.89 &  0.00 &  8.47 &  5.43 \\
8  &  9.91 & 10.09 &  7.08 &  7.02 &  7.38 &  6.97 &  8.59 &  8.47 &  0.00 &  6.40 \\
9  & 11.49 &  9.93 &  8.89 &  8.35 &  6.01 &  8.26 & 10.44 &  5.43 &  6.40 &  0.00 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, but we don't know how wide your paper is?/how much margins you have?/or the documentclass used. However, here are some suggestions:

1. Use a smaller (but still readable) fontsize, `\footnotesize`.
2. Use sanserif shape as it is more readable at smaller fontsize, `\sffamily`.
3. Shrink the inter-column space, `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}`.
4. Add two `@{}`s around the tabular column specifier to trim any outer space.
5. Last and most important, consider using `sidewaysfigure` to gain more space.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[]{subfig}
\usepackage{rotating,booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaysfigure}[hbt!]
    \centering
    \subfloat[\label{Airline:a}]{\includegraphics[width=0.46\textwidth]{a.eps}} \quad
    \subfloat[\label{Airline:b}]{\includegraphics[width=0.46\textwidth]{b.eps}} \\
    \subfloat[\label{Airline:c}]{\includegraphics[width=0.46\textwidth]{c.eps}} \quad
    \subfloat[\label{Airline:d}]{\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}\footnotesize\sffamily
    \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}lrrrrrrrrrr@{}}
    \toprule
    {} &     0 &     1 &     2 &     3 &     4 &     5 &     6 &     7 &     8 &     9 \\
    \midrule
    0  &  0.00 & 14.45 &  9.33 &  9.14 & 10.77 &  7.52 &  8.15 & 11.86 &  9.91 & 11.49 \\
    1  & 14.45 &  0.00 & 10.13 & 11.73 & 10.17 & 11.12 & 10.61 & 10.74 & 10.09 &  9.93 \\
    2  &  9.33 & 10.13 &  0.00 &  8.18 &  7.93 &  7.91 &  7.33 &  8.87 &  7.08 &  8.89 \\
    3  &  9.14 & 11.73 &  8.18 &  0.00 &  9.09 &  6.12 &  9.30 &  8.92 &  7.02 &  8.35 \\
    4  & 10.77 & 10.17 &  7.93 &  9.09 &  0.00 &  8.00 &  8.78 &  7.58 &  7.38 &  6.01 \\
    5  &  7.52 & 11.12 &  7.91 &  6.12 &  8.00 &  0.00 &  6.70 &  9.21 &  6.97 &  8.26 \\
    6  &  8.15 & 10.61 &  7.33 &  9.30 &  8.78 &  6.70 &  0.00 & 10.89 &  8.59 & 10.44 \\
    7  & 11.86 & 10.74 &  8.87 &  8.92 &  7.58 &  9.21 & 10.89 &  0.00 &  8.47 &  5.43 \\
    8  &  9.91 & 10.09 &  7.08 &  7.02 &  7.38 &  6.97 &  8.59 &  8.47 &  0.00 &  6.40 \\
    9  & 11.49 &  9.93 &  8.89 &  8.35 &  6.01 &  8.26 & 10.44 &  5.43 &  6.40 &  0.00 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}    
    } \\
    \caption{Descriptive Statistics}
    \label{Airline}
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! It works well!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, however since the table is huge, the figure not looks very nice :-(

```
\documentclass{article}
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%
\usepackage{lipsum}                             % for dummy text
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[demo,
            export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[hbt!]
\setkeys{Gin}{width=0.4\textwidth}
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
    \subfloat[\label{Airline:a}]{\includegraphics{a}} \hfil
    \subfloat[\label{Airline:b}]{\includegraphics{b}} 
    
\medskip
    \subfloat[\label{Airline:c}]{\includegraphics[valign=T]{c}} \hfil
    \subfloat[\label{Airline:d}]{\footnotesize
    \begin{tabular}[t]{lrrrrrrrrrr}
\toprule
{} &     0 &     1 &     2 &     3 &     4 &     5 &     6 &     7 &     8 &     9 \\
\midrule
0  &  0.00 & 14.45 &  9.33 &  9.14 & 10.77 &  7.52 &  8.15 & 11.86 &  9.91 & 11.49 \\
1  & 14.45 &  0.00 & 10.13 & 11.73 & 10.17 & 11.12 & 10.61 & 10.74 & 10.09 &  9.93 \\
2  &  9.33 & 10.13 &  0.00 &  8.18 &  7.93 &  7.91 &  7.33 &  8.87 &  7.08 &  8.89 \\
3  &  9.14 & 11.73 &  8.18 &  0.00 &  9.09 &  6.12 &  9.30 &  8.92 &  7.02 &  8.35 \\
4  & 10.77 & 10.17 &  7.93 &  9.09 &  0.00 &  8.00 &  8.78 &  7.58 &  7.38 &  6.01 \\
5  &  7.52 & 11.12 &  7.91 &  6.12 &  8.00 &  0.00 &  6.70 &  9.21 &  6.97 &  8.26 \\
6  &  8.15 & 10.61 &  7.33 &  9.30 &  8.78 &  6.70 &  0.00 & 10.89 &  8.59 & 10.44 \\
7  & 11.86 & 10.74 &  8.87 &  8.92 &  7.58 &  9.21 & 10.89 &  0.00 &  8.47 &  5.43 \\
8  &  9.91 & 10.09 &  7.08 &  7.02 &  7.38 &  6.97 &  8.59 &  8.47 &  0.00 &  6.40 \\
9  & 11.49 &  9.93 &  8.89 &  8.35 &  6.01 &  8.26 & 10.44 &  5.43 &  6.40 &  0.00 \\
\bottomrule
    \end{tabular}} 
\caption{Descriptive Statistics}
    \label{Airline}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines show text borders)